# Alignment is not proper in tabview window in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have created a tabview window in cocoa application but the alignment is not proper. Attached screenshot. Any idea how to make it proper.

[image: My Tab View Distance Issue]

The distance is not proper in bottom. Any idea?

Comment: cnt able to see your screeshot

Comment: fixed.  I used "clear constraints".

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue as 
open .xib file -> select "Resolve Auto Layout setting" from bottom (red circle showing in image) -> select "Clear Constraints" (red rectangle in image).[image]